# How to scale values if the feature values are already between -1 and 1 in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a Pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
    Month Sin   Month Cos   Hour Sin    Hour Cos    close
0   0.5         0.866025    0.258819    0.965926    430.78
1   0.5         0.866025    0.500000    0.866025    430.62
2   0.5         0.866025    0.707107    0.707107    432.84
3   0.5         0.866025    0.866025    0.500000    436.12
4   0.5         0.866025    0.965926    0.258819    435.99
```

I want to use the first 4 columns `['Month Sin', 'Month Cos', 'Hour Sin', 'Hour Cos']` as my feature values to predict `close` value using any Machine Learning algorithm (a regression problem basically).

My features which are the first 4 columns are already between -1 and 1. So, my question is that is it necessary to scale the values using `MinMaxScaler` or `StandardScaler` if the feature values are already between -1 and 1?

And do I need to scale my target variable `close` or not? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that depends on if the values have a range that is not -1 to 1. For example, if the range is smaller, they'd still need to be scaled.

Comment: So you are saying I don't need to scale my feature values in this case??

Comment: cos and sin already have a range of -1 to 1 so, correct, they don't need to be scaled.

Comment: And what about the target variable `close`? Should I scale it between (-1,1) or (0,1) or is it not necessary??

Comment: I believe your target values definitely need to be normalized though you might be ok with your feature data. However, both `MinMaxScaler` and `StandardScaler` will have an effect on your data (it'll set the `Month Cos` and `Month Sin` to 0) and I recommend you to do it anyway.

Comment: As usual in ML: try it. If it works keep it, if not ditch it.

Comment: @ARK1375 should I normalize my target variable between (0,1) or between (-1,1) since my feature variables are between -1 and 1.

Comment: @Junaid It doesn't matter. If you are using regression both will work ok. However if you are doing logistic regression, I usually prefer the (0,1) range but (-1,1) will also work just fine. Go with the julien idea. Use both and test how each one performs and chose the best one.

Answer (score -2):

you can use SVC algorithm for predict close